# Compiling opencv example trouble

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to compile this opencv c++ code :

## include

## include

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
Mat img=imread("s.jpg");
namedWindow("Display",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("Display",img);

cv::waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

when I use this command :

```
g++ test.cpp -o exec -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui
```

I get :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccHJ1OKR.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi'
//usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And when I use this command :

```
g++ test.cpp -o exec `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

I get :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lippicv
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My openCV is the 3.1.0 version 
My g++ is the 5.4.0 version and I have the ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

What do you think ?

thank you

Comment: In the first scenario it's hinting that you also ought to link with `opencv_imgcodecs`...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and it's just a user problem, try again but as administrator or superuser.